# Fastest way to marshal data to c++

Tags: c#, interop

I have this one dll function in my C++ header:

```
DLLEXPORT void __stdcall MultiplyQuaternions(double* a, double* b, double* c);
```

`a` and `b` are two 4-element arrays containing a quaternions x,y,z and w component.
`c` is the resulting quaternion.

When called from c++ this function runs incredibly fast.

From C# im prototyping the function as follows:

```
[DllImport("Intrinsics.dll", EntryPoint = "?MultiplyQuaternions@@YAXPEAN00@Z", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void MultiplyQuaternions(double* a, double* b, double* c);
```

The invocation is then like this:

```
fixed (double* q1ptr = q1Vals, q2ptr = q2Vals, resPtr = resVal)
{
    MultiplyQuaternions(q1ptr, q2ptr, resPtr);
}
```

It works, but the performance sucks. The same workload issued from c# takes about 50 times as long as from c++.
What can I do here. Any hint is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The C++ code is too simple, a C++ compiler will always inline this function.  That cannot happen when you pinvoke it.  So you always pay for the call overhead plus the pinvoke marshaller overhead, neither of which is particularly large.  But percentage-wise it will be big when the function takes so very little time.  You need to write this function in C# instead.

Comment: Of course, but I wanted to play around with Avx and see what it can do for Quaternion/Matrix multiplications etc. And as far as I know thats not available in C#.

Comment: It is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.quaternion(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Yes, thats a quat using SIMD to be faster than my own implementation (when used from c#). So there must be some way to improve marshalling speed further, I guess? To clarify the question: I'm not looking for a fast implementation. Its more about the learning aspect. The inlining hint is a thing. So the possibilities may be limited. On the other hand the Numerics.Quaternion.Multiply is still way faster than my own simd implementation when called from C#.

Comment: Well, you can ask a question about it, be sure to show your code.  Pinvoke isn't going to get you there is scratch that one off.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the `[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]` and related attributes.  IIUC, by default when you call into unmanaged code, and stack walk is performed to make sure that everything leading up to that call has permissions to make the call into unmanaged code.  This check is done each time the call into unmanaged code is made and can add up.

Edit: I would also look into using `extern 'C'` or some other means to eliminate the name mangling.  Looking for `MultiplyQuaternions` is easier than looking for `?MultiplyQuaternions@@YAXPEAN00@Z` and you do not have to worry about the possibility of the signature format changing in the future.

Comment: Yeah, that is a first good step in the right direction. Down from 50 times slower to around 15 times. Of course I'm still curious if there is more one can do. :)

Comment: It this makes a measurable difference then you are not measuring correctly.  Including the jitting overhead in the measurement is not useful.  Benchmarking is a tricky art, be sure to get it right with the popular BenchmarkDotNet nuget package.

Comment: Will do that tomorrow. Thanks for the hint. I was measuring with Diagnostics.Stopwatch and chrono::highresclock ^^